# Spring restTemplate.exchange throwing XML parsererror at server side

Tags: xml, spring, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am using restTemplate.exchange or restTemplate.postForObject method at client side where I am passing request with headers and authentication method.

At server side with other system, it throws error as

```
  Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
  Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:604) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
   at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractCollectionJaxbProvider.readFrom(AbstractCollectionJaxbProvider.java:344) ~[jersey-media-jaxb-2.24.1.jar:?]
```

Thus throwing error as

```
   ERROR com.....ExceptionHandler   - Exception occurred while processing the request! javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
```

What is going wrong here? 
I have tried sending minimal params only mandatory ones, tried exchange() and postForObject() method.

The request XML generated out of this httpEntity below works fine in postman

here is my service class -

```
@Service("Service")
public class Service {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Service.class);

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public String postRequest(String loanId, Request requestXml, Map<String, String> headersInfo) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//  ResponseEntity<GenericResponse<Response>>    response = null;
    Response     response = null;
//  String response = null;
    List<String> riskReductionIdList  = null;
    String riskReductionId  = null;
    String responseString = null;

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    headers.set("-External-System-ID", headersInfo.get("ExternalSystemId"));
    headers.set("-External-User-ID", headersInfo.get("ExternalUserId"));
    String plainCredentials=headersInfo.get("User") + ":" + headersInfo.get("Password");

    String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredentials.getBytes()));

      byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( 
              plainCredentials.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );

    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));

    StringWriter request = new StringWriter();

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
        marshaller.marshal(requestXml, request);
        logger.error(" request : " + request.toString());

    } catch (JAXBException e1) {
        logger.error("Exception happened in coverting the request for logging",e1);
    }


    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestXml, headers);

    logger.error(" Request Body: " + httpEntity.getBody());
    logger.error(" Request headers: " + httpEntity.getHeaders());

    try{
    //  response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<GenericResponse<Response>>() {} );
        response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, httpEntity, Response.class);

    }catch(HttpClientErrorException ex){
        logger.error(" Error while sending data to  for loan id : " + loanId + "\n Error : "+ ex.getMessage());
        logger.error(" responseBody : " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString() + "\n statusText : "+ ex.getStatusText() + "\n statusCode : "+ ex.getStatusCode());

    }catch(HttpServerErrorException ex){
        logger.error(" Error while sending data to  for loan id : " + loanId + "\n Error : "+ ex.getMessage());
        logger.error(" responseBody : " + ex.getResponseBodyAsString() + "\n statusText : "+ ex.getStatusText() + "\n statusCode : "+ ex.getStatusCode());

    }catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error(" Error while sending data to  for loan id : " + loanId + "\n Error : "+ ex.getMessage());

    }

    responseString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?> <response>     <code>0</code>     <status>SUCCESS</status>     <messages/>     <payload>        "
            + " <riskReductionIds>             <riskReductionId>10000</riskReductionId>         </riskReductionIds>     </payload> </response>";

    return riskReductionId;
}

}
```

Comment: are you able to print the requestXml generated by client before posting to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

rest Template I was using had code to convert JSOn object. 
I created a restTemplate which worked.